# How to get text of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the following:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
$wikiDOM = $("<document>"+wikiHTML+"</document>");
if($wikiDOM.find(".infobox th:contains('Duration')").length > 0) {
  $("#results").append("<li>" + $wikiDOM.find($(".infobox th:contains('Duration')").siblings("td").html()) + "</li>");
  }
});
```

I am getting a list with:

> [object Object]

I should be getting a text that says:

> Long term

The html where the text is:

```
<th>
   Duration
</th>
<td>Long term</td>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/188/)

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: what is inside that `[object Object]`?

Comment: can you show us the output of `console.log(wikiHTML);`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee updated with a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/188/

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal updated with a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/188/

Comment: @AlivetoDie updated with a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/188/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That argument in the `find` method should be a selector but you're passing in the result of `html()`.

Corrected:

```
$('#results').append('<li>' + $wikiDOM.find('.infobox th:contains("Duration")').siblings('td').html() + '</li>');
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5osb1qjm/1/**

Answer (score -3):

**JavaScript: get Elements value/text by using getElementById("").innerHTML;
JQuery: $(id/class).text();**

Comment: Please, take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).